# How to punctuate lists that are nested to three levels?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, lists

A basic list is punctuated like this:

> The park has some bears, deers, and other animals.
>
> (bears) (deers) (other animals)

When commas appear inside the items of a list, or when lists appear inside other lists, I often see semi-colons used, e.g.:

> The park has: some bears; many deers, which are quite friendly, like to eat camp food, and watch visitors; and other animals, most of which live in the trees.
>
> (bears) (deers (friendly) (like to eat) (watch visitors)) (other animals (live in trees))

When semi-colons appear inside the items of a list, or when lists appear inside lists of other lists, what punctuation can be used?

> (bears) (deers (friendly) (like to eat (popcorn) (marshmallows) (chips)) (watch visitors)) (other animals (live in (tall trees) (short trees))

Update:

To clarify, I am not looking for a way to reword the sentences. I am looking for a way to punctuate the lists in these situations.

Comment: The plural of deer is deer

Comment: Ususally, yes, but not always. The OED has three citations showing 'deers'.

Comment: My advice is to not do it. Three levels will be difficult for readers to understand, no matter how carefully you punctuate.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a bullet or numbered list, which easily allows arbitrary levels of nesting and will be much easier to read?

Comment: {bears [cuddly] [furry] [like to eat visitors who feed deer (popcorn) (marshmallows) (chips) (other food that harms their digestion)]} {park rangers [helpful] [like to arrest visitors who feed deer (popcorn) (marshmallows) (chips) (other food that harms their digestion) unless they (leave) (stop <feeding animals inappropriate food> <littering>) (get eaten by bears)]}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not always appropriate, bulleted lists naturally take care of the nesting problem. In addition, they help individualize the reading experience by allowing the reader to drill down into interesting areas while skipping others.

> The park has:
>
> - bears
>
>   - grizzlies, which number in the tens
>
>     - Attacks are much rarer than the media would lead you to believe, but they do happen.
>   - brown bears, which number in the thousands
> - many deer, which are quite friendly, like to eat camp food, and watch visitors
> - other animals, most of which live in the trees

Comment: +1 The only way to make the three levels explicit is to make them explicit.

Answer (score 15):

> The park has some bears, many deer (which are quite friendly, like to
>   eat camp food, and watch visitors) and other animals, most of which
>   live in the trees.

Comment: +1 because it doesn't look awkward in the least. Dashes could be an alternative to parentheses, but it looks nice as it is.

Comment: If you REALLY have to structure the sentence this way, this is probably the best way to punctuate it. But don't.

Comment: However, this doesn't do the third level of nesting which the OP asked about.

Comment: For a third level, one would use brackets (`[ ]`) within the parentheses.

Comment: +1. @AndrewLeach I have a list that contains level one elements, some of which are level two (and could even be level three or more level three); more level one elements, some of which could again be level two (which could be level three) or more level two; and even more level one elements.

Comment: @zpletan: This seems to be making very heavy weather out of describing some animals in a park.

Comment: Yeah, but it has three levels, unlike your answer (as I read it). I liked your use of parentheses, though, so I simply used them for the third level.

Comment: When i read this, i find myself wondering how many deer live in the trees.

Comment: @cHao: true - restoring the extra comma from the OP's first example (before "and other animals") would help get rid of this ambiguity.

Comment: To avoid the deer in trees ambiguity, could do:  "The park... visitors), and other animals (most of which live in the trees)."

Comment: Best answer, but the use of an Oxford comma in the level 2 list, but not in the level 1 list, bothers me. I'm guessing it's to make it clear that the previous list has ended and the comma following "and other animals" is not part of the list set. The issue is that it is, it's part of the last item in the list, so I'd still write it like this: 
`The park has some bears, many deer (which are quite friendly, like to eat camp food, and watch visitors), and other animals (most of which live in the trees).`

Answer (score 8):

You end up with something like

> The park has: some bears; many deer, like roe deer which are quite friendly, like to eat camp food, and watch visitors — also fallow deer which are timid; and other animals, most of which live in the trees.

That would work, but it's awkward and although a dash seems to work, you can really only have one of those and it's still very easy to get lost in the lists. I would separate the detail into another sentence. You can add further detail like this quite easily.

> The park has: some bears; many deer; and other animals, most of which live in the trees. The park's roe deer are quite friendly, like to eat camp food and watch visitors; the fallow deer are quite timid. Tree-dwelling animals include chimpanzees, which can be quite fierce; and macaques, which are rarely seen at all.

I'm not sure about the last semi-colon in that example. (Oh, and I usually use *deer*.)

Comment: +1 Somehow I missed your answer, and basically duplicated it.

Answer (score 4):

The first level punctuation is the comma, and second, the semicolon.

There is no standard/ official/ recommended/ conventional or specialized stylistic device that I know of at the third level.

So, either improvise, or avoid a third level of nesting in the interest of readability.

Answer (score 3):

> The park has some bears and many deer. The deer are quite friendly, they like to eat camp food and watch visitors. The park also has lots of tree dwelling animals

Answer (score 1):

You could use commas for the first level, and em-dashes for the second level.  Since the second level is composed solely of verbs and the third level is composed of nouns again, you can phrase it like so:

The park has bears, deer — which are friendly, like to eat popcorn, marshmallows, and chips, and like to watch visitors — and other animals — which live in tall trees and short trees.

It is important to note that the verbs must all be in the same structure at the point where they begin.  You can't say "are friendly, like to eat ..., and watch..."  You have to say "are friendly, like to eat..., and like to watch..."  The first way would be suitable for "like to eat..., watch..., and make friends..."

Whenever you have 3 or more structures in a list, especially when they include a verb, you have to make sure they all break at the same point.  Eg: if the order of words were dictated by numbers, you could have "1a 2a 3a, 2b 3b, and 2c 3c."  But you could not have "1a 2a 3a, 2b 3b, and 3c."  If sentence part 1 does not make sense with sentence part 3 (eg "go ... the store") then it becomes unclear if you are implying 2a or 2b between 1a and 3c.

Semicolons should be reserved for bringing two complete sentences closer together; they are like periods where the sentences are related.

> This sentence is incorrect; when this clause can't stand alone.

Comment: Why do visitors — and other animals — live in tall trees? (At least a short phrase surrounded by em dashes gives this idea. Since the whole sentence has an odd number of em dashes, their grouping is left to the reader, and a shorter group seems more plausible.)