# What is the proper punctuation for examples that describe items in a list?

Tags: grammar, lists

How would you punctuate a sentence that contains a list of items, with several examples for each item. For example:
"I have found an existing relationship of qualities through a certain model: words including, between and after; colors red, yellow and blue; numbers five, six and ten."

Notice how the first set seems confusing? The main qualities are words, colors and numbers; with each quality having a set of examples. How could this be made more clear, without changing the ultimate structure of the sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I put a list into a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359797/can-i-put-a-list-into-a-list) // [How to punctuate lists that are nested to three levels](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64557/how-to-punctuate-lists-that-are-nested-to-three-levels/64592#64592) and others.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead say:

> words *such as* between and after; colors *such as* red, yellow, and blue;
>   and numbers *such as* five, six, and ten.

The repeated structure helps identify them as matching members of the set.  That is, because they're all laid out the same -- X such as A, B, and C -- they are easily identifiable as equivalents.